# What is the difference between "State" and "Sovereign" in The Social Contract?

Tags: political-theory

In the last paragraph of *Of The Social Contract, Or Principles of Political Right* by Jean Jacques Rousseau, book I, [chapter 6](http://www.constitution.org/jjr/socon_01.htm#006), there is the following paragraph:

> At once, in place of the individual personality of each contracting
>   party, this act of association creates a moral and collective body,
>   composed of as many members as the assembly contains votes, and
>   receiving from this act its unity, its common identity, its life and
>   its will. This public person, so formed by the union of all other
>   persons formerly took the name of city,4 and now takes that of
>   Republic or body politic; **it is called by its members State when
>   passive. Sovereign when active**, and Power when compared with others
>   like itself. Those who are associated in it take collectively the name
>   of people, and severally are called citizens, as sharing in the
>   sovereign power, and subjects, as being under the laws of the State.
>   But these terms are often confused and taken one for another: it is
>   enough to know how to distinguish them when they are being used with
>   precision.

What is the difference between passive and active in the sentence "it is called by its members State when **passive**. Sovereign when **active**"?

I tried to find in the text, but the keywords "passive" and "active" are not defined or explained before.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question

Comment: It is not a homework; it is a question from a physicist who got stuck on that paragraph while reading it, but if you think it makes sense, I can tag it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of it based on the general meanings of the words (and I couldn't find any sources to back this up) is as follows:

- When the "body politic" is acting (i.e. passing or enforcing laws), it is considered a **Sovereign**
- When the "body politic" is not acting, and just existing (i.e. discussing it), it is considered a **State**
- When the "body politic" is being compared to other States, it is considered a **Power**

In other words: **When the State acts, it is called the Sovereign,** or **The State *is*, and the Sovereign *does*.**

Comment: " When the State acts for/against its people is called the Sovereign, or The State because it exists, and a Power when it can act against another similar body." **Doesn't that read better?** +1 otherwise. (Youhave Soverign twice and are missing Power in your last paragraph.

Comment: @user1873, in my opinion it does not read better. His point was exactly that, when the state acts independently of whether is for people or other entity, is sovereign. I agree with the sentence.

Comment: @user1873 - My understanding is that **Power** only applies to comparisons, both actively and passively.  As in, "The two Powers exist" (vs "The State exists") or "The two Powers agreed" (vs "The Sovereign agreed").